Spark Structured Streaming: Stream-Stream joins with aggregations not writing
Platform: Databricks Notebooks| Language: PySpark
Context: I am trying to build a node in my streaming data pipeline, which evaluates the count of rows are all present (e.g. count(*) == expected_count field), by dynamically joining in real-time and applying a filter to rows only where the check is true.
My notebook uses structured streaming to perform some basic joins and aggregations, however I get to the writeStream and data doesn't seem to write to ADLS. Below is my described code:

First read in tables as streaming datafames

table1_df = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(table1_path)
table2_df = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(table2_path).withColumn("insertion_time", current_timestamp())


Perform a streaming join

joined_df = (table1_df.join(table2_df, field == field, "inner")


Create df to find count of rows

count_df = joined_df.withWatermark("insertion_time", "1 second").groupBy("insertion_time", "Id").agg(count("*").alias("current_count"))


Join the count onto the joined dataframe

joined_with_count_df = joined_df.join(count_df, on=field, how="inner").withColumn("row_count_check", "b.current_count" == "a.expected_count")


Filter row count to only where they match

final_df = joined_with_count_df.filter("row_count_check" == True)


Write the stream

final_df.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", c_path).start(output_path)

I found that the final_df does create the folder in ADLS but does not write any parquet data, same for joined_with_count_df. However joined_df DOES write to ADLS. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

There are several problems with the code above, that maybe fixing them will find the answer.
First, you don't introduce field. I suppose it is correctly specified.
Then, the joined DF produces output as it is well written. However, in the following steps you have several errors. For instance, in step 4 you write "b.current_count" == "a.expected_count". Note how this is a normal Python test, that returns a value (False), NOT a column comparison specification.
There are several ways of specifying that comparison, but you have to use actual Column values to obtain a correct comparison expression (just an example):
from pyspark.sql.column import Column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

col_current_count: Column = col("current_count")
col_expected_count: Column = col("expected_count")
check_expression: Column = col_current_count == col_expected_count

...

join...withColumn("row_count_check", check_expression)

Note how check_expression is also a column, that results from the expression equality between two columns (not strings as in your code).
The same can be applied with the step 5 filter, which could be written as:
final_df = joined_with_count_df.filter(col("row_count_check") == lit(True))

(lit in this case converts the literal value in a column to be compared with the value.)
Try along the lines of these changes.

Apologies for the vagueness in some of the code, had to sanitize it so contained some mistakes and assumptions that you rightly picked up on. I will give that method of evaluating the check a go soon and report back, many thanks
